# Graph API get tagged photos from News Feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm trying to get all photos from a user's newsfeed on facebook using graph api. and I mean all. so far, I think i only get the posted photos, but neccessarily the ones a user commented on, was tagged an, or the friends where tagged in. is there any way to get those photos at all with graph api? I know there is always FQL, but I'd rather not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesnt seem to be a way to do so. So I had to revert to the following FQL:

```
SELECT message, description, attachment FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'app_2305272732'
```

The photo is in attachment then and you might want to filter against albums